# Search in data in php error

Tags: php

Thank in advance any idea? I been trying to solve this thank you ver much

```
 <?php
    mysqli_connect("localhost","root","bsithg1","webproj") or die("Could not connect");

$output='';
    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM remittancetracking WHERE TrackingNo LIKE '%$searchq%' OR amount LIKE '%$searchq%'");

$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($count == 0){
$output =   ' There was no search result';
}else{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array(query)){

        $ns=$row['namereceiver'];
        $cn=$row['ContactNosender'];
    $output .= '<div>'.$ns.''.$cn.'</div>'; 
    }

}

}

?>
<form method="POST">
<input type="TEXT" name="search" placeholder="Search for Tracking Number..."/>
<input type="SUBMIT" name= "" value="OK"/>
</form>
<?php print("$output");?>
```

it gave me this two errors

> ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given
>   in C:\wamp64\www\Project\search.php on line 8
>
> ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, null

Search for Tracking Number...
  OK
There was no search result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
mysqli_connect("localhost","root","bsithg1","webproj") or die("Could not connect");
```

Into:

```
$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","bsithg1","webproj");
```

And then change:

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM remittancetracking WHERE TrackingNo LIKE '%$searchq%' OR amount LIKE '%$searchq%'");
```

Into:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM remittancetracking WHERE TrackingNo LIKE '%$searchq%' OR amount LIKE '%$searchq%'");
```

**WHY?**

Because you are missing this parameter in your `mysqli_query`:

> **Link**
>
> Procedural style only: A link identifier returned by mysqli_connect() or mysqli_init()

***Source:*** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: thank you I followed your advice it gives me this error 
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string,  thank you for the help

Comment: The error already said it. Check if the 2nd parameter is a string.

Comment: Also this `mysqli_fetch_array(query)` won't work ;-)